# How can I send ADA to a Yoroi wallet?

Tags: wallet, ada, yoroi

I have created a new Yoroi wallet and I want to send ADA to the newly created Yoroi wallet, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to the Yorio FAQ for this: https://yoroi-wallet.com/#/faq/2

> To receive Ada go to the Receive tab in your wallet and generate an address. Use a button in the user interface to copy it to the clipboard and then share it with the person who is going to send you Ada.