# How to transfer ADA from Daedalus wallet to Yoroi wallet?

Tags: wallet, ada, daedalus

I have created a new Yoroi wallet but I want to transfer ADA from Daedalus wallet, but I don't know how.

For example:

I have 20 ADA that I want to send to a Yoroi wallet and I want to send them from a Daedalus wallet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get your Yoroi wallet address. See [How to send ADA to Yoroi wallet?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/q/2029/1142)
2. In Daedalus send some ADA to this address.

Alternatively, you can also restore the Daedalus wallet in Yoroi if you just want to switch the wallet applocation. To do this you can use the restore function in Yoroi. Then you'll see the 20 ADA from Daedolus in Yoroi. This is not a transaction, you just imported the wallet in Yoroi. Yoroi and Daedalus are just different tools to manage your wallet.